R unicode symbol not saved in ggplot with cairo_pdf
I would like to use a unicode symbol in a ggplot that I would then like to save as a PDF but this never seems to work.
Here is the plot:
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

test <- ggplot() + geom_text(aes(x = 1, y = 2, label = "\u2699"))
test

When using the agg backend, I can plot the outcome in RStudio:

I can also save it as a PNG without a problem.
Now, when I try to save it as a PDF/vector graphic, I fail:
ggsave(test, file = "test1.pdf", device = Cairo::CairoPDF)
ggsave(test, file = "test2.pdf", device = grDevices::cairo_pdf)
ggsave(test, file = "test3.pdf", device = cairo_pdf)
ggsave(test, file = "test4.pdf")

With all of them I get only something like this:

This also happens when I change the backend device to Cairo in RStudio.
I have already installed the "Arial Unicode MS" font, but to no avail it seems.
I have already tried using the {emojifont} package but that does not contain the relevant unicode symbol.
My attempt to use maybe HTML for it also failed similarly:
ggplot() + geom_richtext(aes(x = 1, y = 2, label = "\u2699"))

Here is the session info:
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Austria.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Austria.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Austria.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Austria.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Vienna
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggtext_0.1.2   extrafont_0.19 ggplot2_3.4.4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.3      dplyr_1.1.2       compiler_4.3.0    tidyselect_1.2.0  Rcpp_1.0.10       xml2_1.3.4        stringr_1.5.0     systemfonts_1.0.4
 [9] scales_1.2.1      textshaping_0.3.6 R6_2.5.1          commonmark_1.9.0  labeling_0.4.2    generics_0.1.3    Cairo_1.6-0       tibble_3.2.1     
[17] munsell_0.5.0     pillar_1.9.0      rlang_1.1.1       utf8_1.2.3        Rttf2pt1_1.3.8    stringi_1.7.12    xfun_0.39         cli_3.6.1        
[25] withr_2.5.0       magrittr_2.0.3    grid_4.3.0        gridtext_0.1.5    rstudioapi_0.14   markdown_1.7      lifecycle_1.0.3   vctrs_0.6.3      
[33] glue_1.6.2        farver_2.1.1      extrafontdb_1.0   ragg_1.2.5        rsconnect_1.1.0   fansi_1.0.4       colorspace_2.1-0  tools_4.3.0      
[41] pkgconfig_2.0.3 

